Unable to deploy next.js app to firebase hosting
It was working fine for a long time, but suddenly when I'm trying to deploy my next.js app to firebase hosting, I receive the following error: Failed to make request to https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/businessflow-ai/sites?pageToken=&pageSize=10
Sometimes it happens immediately after the 'firebase deploy' command and sometimes it starts the building process and only happens at the end. In either case, the app is never deployed to firebase.
When opening the link, the following more detailed error appears:
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"method": "google.firebase.hosting.v1beta1.MetadataService.ListSites",
"service": "firebasehosting.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}
This is strange because I am logged in and it used to work just fine. The only reason I can think of is that I changed my physical location (so also different internet provider etc.) but I don't see why that should be an issue.
Any insight would be helpful. Thank you.
I tried to logout and login again, tried to reinstall firebase and re-initialize it in my project. I also tried to create a new project both in next.js and firebase but all have the same issue.
